# Winforms Change Label Properties in Usercontrol from Parent Form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to change the `label` and `text` of a label which is inside a `UserControl` from within a Parent `Form` method at runtime.

So within the method in parent `Form` I do the following to change the label properties which is inside a `UserControl`

```
public partial class Form : Form
{
    public void Form_Method()
    {
        UserControl uc = new UserControl();
        uc.UpdateLabel(true);
    }
}
```

And the custom method inside my `UserControl`

```
public partial Class UserControl : UserControl
{
    public void UpdateLabel(bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            lbl.Text = "This";
            lbl.Forecolor = Color.Green;
        }

        if (value == false)
        {
            lbl.Text = "That";
            lbl.Forcolor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

However when I navigated to the `UserControl` the label properties have not changed as I was creating a `new` instance of the usercontrol on the fly which 
technically disappears after the method ends.

So I tried creating a public property of the actual `UserControl` as follows

```
public partial class Form : Form
{
    public UserControl _uc;

    public void Form_Method()
    {
        UserControl uc2 = new UserControl();    
        uc2.UpdateLabel(true);
        _uc = uc2;
    }
}
```

However it has no effect whatsoever? I have come across info of using `Events` or `Delegates` am not sure if they are the correct process for what am trying to do?

Comment: why make a new copy of the control?

Comment: I dont see you using the usercontrol on your form.. its just an empty form

Comment: @BugFinder I have edited my question.

Comment: You forget to add the control to `Controls` collection of the form. Also if you are going to update an existing control, you don't need to create a new one, just find it and update it, for example `this.userControl1.UpdateLabel(true);`

Comment: Well if you made it _uc on the form, then _uc.UpdateLabel(true) should be enough

Comment: @BugFinder do I not need to create an instance of the UserControl before I set the label properties inside the usercontrol?

Comment: @BugFinder  I will get `Object reference set to a null` if I don't initialise the `UserControl`

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the designer and you already added a `UserControl` to your form? If so it has a `name` property, reference it using that name.

Comment: @Rotem the `UserControl` unfortunately is not on the `Form`.

Comment: Then follow @RezaAghaei's advice.

Comment: I think @RezaAghaei is also assuming the `Control` is on the `Form`

Comment: @Kevin Well where is it then?

Comment: @Rotem its on a different `Form`

Comment: @Kevin So get a reference to that form if you don't have one, and either get the usercontrol reference from that form, or route the update call to that form.

Comment: if the control is on another form, say Form2, then just do `form2.UserControl1.UpdateLabel(true);` Just stop creating new usercontrols in your code to change the label, because then you dont change the label from the existing usercontrol but the new created one and that is not what you need

Comment: @GuidoG Why didn't I think of that solution :)